# MySql how to compare this years month to last years month?

Tags: mysql, date

How do I find the department numbers who have produced more than 20% more sales in them this February (as in this year so would use YEAR(CURDATE()) rather than saying "2012") compared to last February as in the year before. The result table should have only one column which contains the department numbers that have produced 20% more sales.

If the febraury last year has no sales for "department 2" but sales for this febraury, then 0 * 1.2= 0 so the results would not show "department 2". If the february last year for "department 3" sold one item, and the february this year sold two items, this would be a 1.5 increase which is more than 1.2 so the results should show "department 3". If there were only 3 departments, at most, there should be only 3 rows.

Department 2 does not appear because there was 3 sales last february and one sale this february. Department 4 does not appear because there was no sale last february so in terms of maths 0 * 1.2 = 0 so Department 4 would not appear despite there being sales this febraury.

Thank you in advance, and hope this is detailed enough.

Comment: Your math is wrong. Department 4 should appear. `2` sales is more than `0 * 1.2` That's `infinite %` increase in sales, which is definitely more than 20%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `having` as below:

```
    select departement_no
    from department
    group by departement_no
    having sum(case date_format(date, '%m%Y') 
                when CONCAT('02',YEAR(CURDATE())) then 1 else 0 end) 
           >
           1.2 * sum(case date_form(date, '%m%Y') 
                     when CONCAT('02',YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Year)))
                     then 1 else 0 end)
         AND 
         sum(case date_form(date, '%m%Y') 
                     when CONCAT('02',YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Year)))
                     then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: this works pretty well, it completes all requirements but one. In that if there was sales on this feb, but no sales on the feb before, that department number should not show up since 0 * 1.2 = 0.

Comment: @AjayPunja Theoretically that is not right. If there was no sale in prior Feb, then any amount of sale in current Feb should show up. Still  if you want to filter out then add one `AND` condition stating prior ear sale should not be null i.e. `sum(case date_form(date, '%m%Y') 
                     when date_format(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Year), 
                                      '%m%Y') then 1 else 0 end) > 0`

Comment: You were right in changing the manual input to CURDATE() instead to find the year to make it useful every year, however it doesnt specifically find "February" anymore.

Comment: @AjayPunja Do you want to compare February every year? If yes, then use `CONCAT('02',YEAR(CURDATE()))`

Comment: Yeah, I want to be able to compare February every year. As it's a query to select the month we like.

Comment: @AjayPunja Use  `CONCAT('02',YEAR(CURDATE()))` and  `CONCAT('02',YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Year)))`. I updated the answer.

Comment: @AjayPunja I updated the answer. Please let me know, if there is any issue as I can't execute the query myself.

Comment: I tried using NOT null, but seem to get an error. Where do I need to put the NOT NULL so it only shows the dates with the increase, and not dates with 0.

Comment: @AjayPunja I didn't say to use not null in query(that was the concept). I posted syntax at the same time. Please revisit my comments above. Any way, updated the answer with that check as well.

Comment: Works perfect. Exactly what's needed. Can you explain how CASE works? I understand most of the code and then I get lost on the keyword CASE.

Comment: @AjayPunja Case is matching your Month and Year resulting from `date_form(date, '%m%Y')` against the when statements i.e. this year FEB or last year Feb. `Else` section is the default i.e. if no match then default. I used `sum` so it yields count of 1's for all records with matching `FEb` and `0` for non matching(is ignored as adding `0` is not having any impact).

Comment: Another quick question, is it possible to substitute the word CASE with boolean logics such as AND, NOT, OR? As I read online CASE means IF-THEN-ELSE type logic, but if I use AND, NOT and OR I think it'd be easier to understand the codes.

Comment: @AjayPunja You may use `if-else` but case is equally readable. Not sure why are you hesitant.

Answer (score 1):

This uses **[`MAKEDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate)** function to craete the first day of a year and then adds the appropriate month intervals to calculate the start of the (February) month and the start date of the next month.

Replace `?` with 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.:

```
SELECT 
    this_year.departement_no
FROM  
      ( SELECT departement_no, COUNT(*) AS num_sales
        FROM department
        WHERE date >= MAKEDATE( YEAR(NOW()), 1) + INTERVAL (?-1) MONTH
          AND date < MAKEDATE( YEAR(NOW()), 1) + INTERVAL (?) MONTH
        GROUP BY departement_no
      ) this_year
    LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT departement_no, COUNT(*) AS num_sales
        FROM department
        WHERE date >= MAKEDATE( YEAR(NOW())-1, 1) + INTERVAL (?-1) MONTH
          AND date < MAKEDATE( YEAR(NOW())-1, 1) + INTERVAL (?) MONTH
        GROUP BY departement_no
      ) last_year
          ON  last_year.departement_no = this_year.departement_no
WHERE 
    this_year.num_sales > 1.2 * COALESCE(last_year.num_sales, 0) ;
```

If you want (as your rather strange requirements) to not show departments that have sales this February and had no sales last year, remove the `COALESCE()` function. You can also change the `LEFT` join to `INNER` join:

```
WHERE 
    this_year.num_sales > 1.2 * last_year.num_sales ;
```

Comment: What is makedate? Something like add/sub_date?

Comment: See the edit. There was a mistake in precious code, it's corrected now.

Comment: How do I not show DepartmentNo that has 0 or null values from last year despite having sales this year?