# Which CD's have had more sales between july and july of last year

Tags: mysql, database

of that sale, as there can be many sales on one date, and would be many rows.

However i am not sure how i can do this.

So far i have:

```
SELECT cd_no
FROM sales
```

I issue i think is in the subquery select, where the alias 'm' is returning 'NULL'

Comment: It'll be very hard to get a usable answer to your question without knowing anything about the data you're querying. Are you storing CD sales in a table? What is the schema of that table, and what is the meaning of a row in that table?

Comment: I only store information of sales by the purchasedate. Each time a purchase is made a row is generated of the purchasedate... so there could be many rows of having the same purchasedate. Counting the purchasedates of one specific date would give you the total sales for that specific date.

Comment: Do you want to include CDs that had no sales last year?

Comment: Identical question: [MySql how to compare this years month to last years month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663433/mysql-how-to-compare-this-years-month-to-last-years-month)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the total number of sales for each CD by grouping by CD_NO and counting rows:

```
SELECT CD_NO, COUNT(*) AS purchases
FROM Sales
GROUP BY CD_NO
```

You can get the number of sales for each CD in a certain date range like this (because `<date condition>` will be 1 when True and 0 when False):

```
SELECT CD_NO, SUM(<date condition>) AS purchases
FROM Sales
GROUP BY CD_NO
```

For July 2012, you can use `purchasedate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31'` or `YEAR(purchasedate) = 2012 AND MONTH(purchasedate) = 7`, among other options.

To compare the two date ranges

```
SELECT
    CD_NO,
    SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31') AS a,
    SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-31') AS b
FROM Sales
GROUP BY CD_NO
```

Finally, to select rows with 15% more purchases...

```
SELECT CD_NO
FROM (
    SELECT
        CD_NO,
        SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31') AS a,
        SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-31') AS b
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY CD_NO) AS t
WHERE t.a > 1.15 * t.b
```

or simply:

```
SELECT CD_NO
FROM Sales
GROUP BY CD_NO
HAVING       SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31') 
     > 1.15 * SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-31') ;
```

Comment: It looks like you have a potential divide-by-zero in there, and you'll include every CD, whether it had sales or not.

Comment: @user1854392 Let me know if you need help fixing the divide by 0 issue.

Comment: this code isnt working correctly

Comment: SELECT CD_no, SUM(YEAR(purchasedate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND MONTH(opdate)=7) as a
FROM Sales
GROUP BY CD_no
HAVING a > 0

Comment: let me edit my code which is almost what i need... however it is not returning what i need.

Comment: could you look at my new code? i have a problem with my sum of purchasedates

Comment: @user1854392 You're new code isn't complete; I suspect you've mis-edited and deleted text and code you meant to keep. Do you prefer the `YEAR(purchasedate) = <year> AND MONTH(purchasedate) = <month>` method or the `purchasedate BETWEEN <start> AND <end>` method?

Comment: This answer performs significantly worse than mine, and was submitted 3 minutes after my correct answer was... and yet it got the checkmark and 3 upvotes while mine got ignored.  -1 to both OP and jmilloy for ruining my day.

Comment: @TheSmose Where is your answer? You should leave it up because many people will read and prefer a faster solution! I'd happily upvote it.